# How to convert parquet file to Avro file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parquet, spark-avro

I am new to hadoop and Big data Technologies. I like to convert a parquet file to avro file and read that data. I search in few forums and it suggested to use AvroParquetReader.

```
AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = new AvroParquetReader<GenericRecord>(file);
GenericRecord nextRecord = reader.read();
```

But I am not sure how to include AvroParquetReader. I am not able 
to import it at all.

I can read this file using spark-shell and may be convert it to some JSON
and then that JSON can be converted to avro. But I am looking for a
simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to use Spark DataFrames, you will be able to read the parquet files natively in Apache Spark, e.g. (in Python pseudo-code):

```
df = spark.read.parquet(...)
```

To save the files, you can use the `spark-avro` Spark Package.   To write the DataFrame out as an avro, it would be something like:

`df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("...")`

Don't forget that you will need to include the right version of the `spark-avro` Spark Package with your version of your Spark cluster (e.g. 3.1.0-s2.11 corresponds to `spark-avro` package 3.1 using Scala 2.11 which matches the default Spark 2.0 cluster). For more information on how to use the package, please refer to https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-avro.

Some handy references include:

1. [Spark SQL Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files)
2. [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-3.1/README.md) Spark Package.

Comment: The OP specifically asks for a simpler solution than spark (shell)

Comment: Or the OP is asking for a simpler solution than using AvroParquetReader to go from Parquet to JSON and then JSON to Avro.

Comment: I understand your take but if you refer the entire question about the use of AvroParquetReader and/or within the context of Spark-shell converting from Parquet to Avro with JSON as the intermediary - then using DataFrames to read from Parquet and save to Avro is a simpler solution.  I can understand the context that perhaps the question is how to convert from Parquet to Avro without using Spark altogether.  But as this question is tagged Apache-spark, I don't think it's unreasonable to provide a simpler solution using Spark.

Comment: I had removed my "take" already since your answer is "fair" interpretation  .But yes - my interest is specifically for standalone *without*  spark.  There appears to be a library for it - am trying it out now.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that you had removed the "take" comment, I guess I was responding to your original comment at the same time ;-).  Good luck with converting without Spark, eh?!   BTW, in the past I had used `parquet-mr` library but admittedly I haven't used it in awhile.